# Is there a way to send multiple wifi camera a signal to take a picture at the same time?

Tags: camera, sony

I have 20 wifi cameras that are compatible with the camera remote api (all identical).
Using the API, is it possible to trigger all of them over wifi to take a picture at the same time?
I would basically like to trigger all 20 over wifi and then fetch the pictures from all of them. So any suggestions for how to do that would be appreciated. Mainly just triggering them together would be a great start.

Also, is it possible to send commands to the camera with the API when the camera is connected to a network via the play memories camera app or can commands only be sent via connections with the Smart Remote Control? Reason being, I can have multiple cameras connect to my network this way, but via the smart remote, I can only connect to a single pc to camera at a time as the camera acts like the hot spot instead of the other way around.
Thanks,
-Scott

Comment: This may be a little bit off topic for S O. What have you tried so far?

Comment: This question is directed to the Sony Remove Camera SDK engineers.This is where Sony has people posting their questions related to their remote camera SDK and API

Answer (score 0):

That would be possible but since it's only possible to connect one camera to one phone at a time, you would need 20 phones as well and then you could send the command to take a picture to all the phones which would in turn trigger the camera connected to each one.

It is not possible to send commands to the camera other than by using the Camera Remote API.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that some cameras use WPS to make outgoing connections (ie. when using 5 AZ1 with LiveViewRemote)....

If you had such a camera maybe you could connect them all to the same WiFi router, and then use the API to initiate a connection to all at the same time and quickly tell each to take a picture in quick succession.

Here's a link which might help you get there:
https://github.com/Bloodevil/sony_camera_api/issues/8