# How to extend Sony Remote Camera API access point range?

Tags: networking, sony, sony-camera-api

Just for reference the Sony Remote Camera API only works by using a [1:1 Wifi Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37929542/2920861)

The Wifi signal strength of my Sony DSC-HX60V camera already drops after a few meters distance. But I want to be able to remotely control the camera over a range of 50 meter. There is no way that the onboard Wifi can achieve this range.
So now Iam looking for a solution to this problem. If it helps a local Wifi router exists that covers the whole range:
[image]

A normal Wifi repeater seems to be the best option, but according to a [Forum Post](https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/3952234) using a repeater does not work, because the repeater acts a client and the camera can only connect to one client at the same time. Did someone got it to work with a repeater?

Additionaly I was thinking about using a Raspberry Pi with a second Wifi adapter that connect to the local Wifi and manages the API requests.

Any other ideas?

Disclaimer:
Even tho this Question may be more Hardware and Network related and thereby fits more into the SuperUser Network. A working Network connection does not necessary imply that the API is working aswell. This is why I posted this Question here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a router which can work in 'client mode' that should be able to make a 1:1 connection with the camera, and then present that link over ethernet - you may have issues with network addresses and/or discovery if your main network is a different IP range to what the camera offers/DHCP's.

Some of the Sony cameras support 'multi-wifi' where the camera connects to an external device (normally the LiveViewRemote, but can be a router). Unfortunately the HX60 (and presumably any of the Play Memories SmartRemote app based ones) does not seem capable of this.... maybe the QX1 is an exception as it's supposed to work like this.

This connection connection is managed via WPS, and once connected the RemoteAPI works well. Works for my AS100.

If you are looking to set up a RaspPi, I can confirm that it works with this Python library:
https://github.com/Bloodevil/sony_camera_api

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xR3gAfu4Hfw

Comment: I was experimenting a lot with my router settings, but I could not even get a ping response by using the static camera IP. However the repo for the python camera API helped me a lot.